# Pushing content onto array

Tags: php

In the following code, the first `print_r` inside the while loop prints different story content. The problem I am having is that the 2nd `print_r` statement produces the exact same story over and over from the `$stories` array.

```
$stories = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $story->name      = $row['Name'];
  ...
  $story->date      = $row['Date'];

  print_r($story); //for testing
  array_push ( $stories , $story );
}

print_r($stories);
```

Edit:
someone asked for command line output, but this is a hosted account. In case the above is not clear though:

From inside loop:

```
(
    [id] => 9370
    [name] => Five Below, Inc.
    ...
)
stdClass Object
(    
    [id] => 9362
    [name] => Peregrine Pharmaceuticals Inc.
    ...
)   
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 9363
    [name] => Mitel Networks Corporation
)
...
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 9370
    [name] => Five Below, Inc.
    ...
)
```

After loop:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9370
            [name] => Five Below, Inc.
            ...
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9370
            [name] => Five Below, Inc.
        ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9370
            [name] => Five Below, Inc.
        )
```

Comment: execute your query in console/phpmyadmin and add output to your question

Comment: The second `print_r` is outside the loop, and `$stories` is assigned within the loop - how should it not be the same every time? Please provide more explanation and some example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com , the database and code are running on a hosted account. Digression: I am wondering if I am supposed to reset story variable each time.

Comment: @Roger - well, in general "yes". But in this case, it may not be necessary as you overwrite both name and date each loop, so it should not be a problem. But from other hand - it looks like this is the culprit. See my answer.

Comment: //in this case, calling the function array_push is not an efficient way of creating array inside a loop.
         $stories[]=$story;  //Instead of 'array_push'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem lies in `$story`. I made test case code:

```
$rows = array(
         array('Name'=>'1', 'Date'=>'21'),
         array('Name'=>'4', 'Date'=>'24'),
);

$stories = array();

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
  $story->name      = $row['Name'];
  $story->date      = $row['Date'];

  array_push( $stories , $story );
}

print_r($stories);
```

produces

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 4
        [date] => 24
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 4
        [date] => 24
    )
```

which is wrong. However adding `unset($story);` and have new object create each time, solves the issue:

```
$rows = array(
         array('Name'=>'1', 'Date'=>'21'),
         array('Name'=>'4', 'Date'=>'24'),
);

$stories = array();

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
  unset( $story );   // replace with whatever code you use to create new object
  $story->name      = $row['Name'];
  $story->date      = $row['Date'];

  array_push( $stories , $story );
}

print_r($stories);
```

gives correct:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 1
        [date] => 21
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 4
        [date] => 24
    )
```